# Adding record via not in list event of combo box

Tags: ms-access-2013

Hopefully someone can help me with this.

On frmMain, I have a listbox (lstAuthor) and a combo box (cboAuthor).  The RowSource for both is a query, qryListAuthor.  Both have two columns, authorID and AuthorName, and the bound column is col 1.

When I start typing the author name in the combo box, I want it to update and when the author I am looking for fills in the current line I am typing, I want to press enter and have the lstAuthor update to that particular record, and be selected.

Plus another listbox called lstBook, to update and show the books written by the author selected in lstAuthor. This is currently happening if I scroll down the list of authors in lstAuthor and select one.

Not in list:

If I am typing the author name in cboAuthor, and the author doesn't exist, I need to press enter and have a form called frmAddAuthorFly open.  After I have added the author, and close the form, I need both cboAuthor and lstAuthor to be updated with the new author, and also the author just added, to be selected in lstAuthor.  And lstBook to update as well.  frmAddAuthorFly has only got three fields; authorID, authorName and authorCategory.

I've wasted a fair amount of time on this, so maybe someone can give the solution.  Many thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spent a bit of time on this today, and this is what I have come up with.  Seems to work ok, but if anyone sees any glaring problems, feel free to offer an alternative.

In the NotInList event of cboAuthor

```
Private Sub cboAuthor_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)
On Error GoTo errline

Dim MsgBoxAnswer As Variant

Response = acDataErrContinue

MsgBoxAnswer = MsgBox("Do you want to add a new author?", vbYesNo, "Add New Author")

If msboxanswer = vbNo Then
Me.cboAuthor = Null
DoCmd.GoToControl "cboAuthor"
GoTo exitline

Else
txtHidden = "addOk"
DoCmd.OpenForm ("frmAddAuthorFly")
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
Forms![frmaddauthorfly]![AuthorName] = NewData
Me.cboAuthor = Null
DoCmd.GoToControl "authorcategory"

End If
exitline:
Exit Sub
errline:
Exit Sub
'Select Case Err.Number

End Sub
```

I've added a cmdButton to frmAddAuthorFly and included the following code:

```
Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
On Error GoTo errline

If Forms![frmmain]![txtHidden] = "addok" Then
Forms![frmmain]![cboAuthor].Requery
Forms![frmmain]![LstAuthor].Requery
Forms![frmmain]![LstAuthor] = Me.AuthorID
Forms![frmmain]![txtHidden] = "AddDone"
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmAddAuthorFly"
Forms![frmmain]![cboAuthor].Requery
Forms![frmmain]![LstAuthor].Requery
Forms![frmmain].[LstAuthor].SetFocus

Else
MsgBox "txt hidden is not addok"
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmaddauthorfly"
End If

errline:
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

One thing that I would have like to do, is after I set the focus on the new author just added record, in the listbox, is have it clicked.  Not just highlighted, but I guess I can click it ...